# Is it possible to rent a bicycle long-term (a month) in Vitória, Brazil?

Tags: brazil, bicycles

I just arrived in Vitória, Brazil, and will be here until the end of May. I don't have a car, and don't want to pay to rent one, but a bicycle would extend my range of mobility significantly.

Is there any place here where I can rent a bicycle for an extended period (as opposed to just for the day, to ride around a park or some such)?

Comment: I don't know if you can, but I imagine it wouldn't be much cheaper than buying a cheap bike at the supermarket. Ok, you probably can rent a good bike, but imagine paying about R$6 per day, in a month you'd spend R$180 and you can buy one in a Carrefour or WalMart for about R$250. How much do you intend to spend?

Comment: @Roberto: I suppose I should consider that.  I ride a US$1700 bicycle at home... so considering a ~US$100 bicycle hadn't really crossed my mind. But I can see what the local Wal-Mart has to offer.

Comment: Or buy a used bike? After a month, you can then just give it away.

Comment: I am possibly heading to Vitoria in March and was wondering the very same thing... So where di you buy a used bike?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some friends and I did some searching, asking at cycling shops, etc, and could not find anyone who rents bicycles. So I followed @Berhard's advice and bought a used one for R$160 (~US$72) and will either sell or give it away when I leave.

Comment: Don't let this answer dissuade you from providing your own if you find a Bicycle rental location in Vitoria. I'll happily accept any new answer along those lines.

Comment: Sorry @Flimzy, but I never heard about bike rentals in Brazil.